# Excel: search for a word in the column and copy it to another column on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table with rows of data. The column J contains various descriptions of goods. I need to search all the rows in this column for the word LATEX and when it is found, copy ONLY this word to the column A on the same sheet on the same row. I was trying to find a solution and came up with this macro using Autofilter, but it is not working properly. Can you please help me?

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

    Dim dataWs As Worksheet
    Dim copyWs As Worksheet
    Dim totRows As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set dataWs = Worksheets("Massiv")
    Set copyWs = Worksheets("Massiv")

    With dataWs
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("J:J")
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="LATEX"
        End With
    End With

    totRows = dataWs.Range("J:J").Rows.count
    lastRow = dataWs.Range("J" & totRows).End(xlUp).Row
    dataWs.Range("J:J" & lastRow).Copy
    copyWs.Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    dataWs.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: Filter is good but you have to deal with rows that are visible and those that are not. Why dont you use a find method and do what you need

Comment: pnuts: the macro runs without error, but does not copy anything

Comment: Bharath Raja: How do I use find? Can you please give an example of a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following changes, your code should work. I've noted the changes in the comments in the code.

```
With dataWs
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("J:J")
         'Use wildcard to search for word LATEX within contents of column J cells 
         .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*LATEX*"
    End With
End With

totRows = dataWs.Range("J:J").Rows.Count
lastRow = dataWs.Range("J" & totRows).End(xlUp).Row
'After filtering, select the visible cells in column A...
Set rng = dataWs.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'... and set their values to "LATEX"
rng.Value = "LATEX"
dataWs.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: Cheers, chuff! Worked liked a dream!